# About the syntax used in systemd sd-device source

Tags: c, syntax, systemd

So, I was reading the source code of libsystemd and found this line that I think can only be some kind of obscure trickery.

Please can someone explain.

Link: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/32243272fff325fbdeb158817fe65d5337f0528d/src/libsystemd/sd-device/sd-device.c#L42

This is the line, so you don't have to open the link to read it.
`device = new(sd_device, 1);` Where `device` is declared right before, as `sd_device *device;` And `sd_device` is a type.

Comment: It has to be a ```macro``` which takes a ```type``` to be allocated and probably a number to provide how many objects to be allocated.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Yes indeed. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`new`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/78bbc7d5d40506bc0b8e90c35ab89b02a904d13a/src/basic/alloc-util.h#L23) is a macro where the *type* `sd_device` in `device = new(sd_device, 1);` is used as `sizeof(sd_device)`:

```c
#define new(t, n) ((t*) malloc_multiply(n, sizeof(t)))
```

After preprocessing, the line in question therefore becomes a call to [`malloc_multiply`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/78bbc7d5d40506bc0b8e90c35ab89b02a904d13a/src/basic/alloc-util.h#L115):

```c
device = ((sd_device*) malloc_multiply(1, sizeof(sd_device)));
```